# Rails 3 working with multiple languages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, gsub

When working with different languages, what is the proper way to sub a string out in Rails?

Example (Czech Translation):

```
str = "pro více informací"
replace = "<em>více</em>"
str["více"] = replace
puts str
```

The problem I keep running into (and this is for multiple languages, not just Czech) is the following: IndexError (string not matched)

Is there a better way to do a string replacement? I know about gsub and sub, but both methods cause the following errors

.gsub! and gsub errors: `RegexpError (invalid multibyte character)`

.sub! and .sub errors: `RegexpError (invalid multibyte character)`

Answer (score 1):

You will want to browse through [this thread](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/133538). Use the byte values for replacement.

Comment: Thanks! I will look at the thread mentioned. What I am doing for an interim solution is I wrote a huge array in JavaScript that contains the weird characters and their HTML equivalents and replacing them with RegEx.